# Scrollview with images still crashes even lazy load?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a scroll view holding a few images, each one is around 100KB. I add them to uiscrollview by creating uiviewcontrollers to hold them. controllers are stored in the scrollview. I remove its view from superview and replace it by some string when the image scrolls out of visible area. I think I'm doing fine. But I still got crash after scrolling a few times(even scroll forth and back on the same 5 images).

I noticed every controller's dealloc is called when it's removed from the scroll view, but not its viewDidUnload.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Plus, sometimes, there will be exceptions that some selector sent to deallocated objects, which are no doubt, view controllers. I strongly doubt releasing view controller might conflict with didMemoryReceiveWarning then viewDidUnload thing.

Comment: The lack of foresight and planning on your part does not constitute the urgency on our part.

Comment: sorry for wording. I'm close to hit the wall now.

Comment: I'm kinda lost. I use the same app framework to build one app with more and larger images. That apps works fine. I need do more investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viewDidUnload` is called when the `viewController` itself released its view. It is **not** called if **you** released the view (which means `viewDidUnload` is only relevant in the memory warning situation). In order to completely delete a view and its view controller, you should remove the view from its superview, then release the view controller. Then it's normal `viewDidUnload` is not called.

It's hard to understand how you implemented this, and why it went wrong. But let me suggest a few things.

The view controller's methods such as `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `viewWillDisappear`, `viewDidDisappear`, etc. are not useful here, because none of them can tell you the view is currently on the screen or not. The only way you can tell is to get the `contentOffset` of the scroll view every time a scroll happens (by delegate methods of UIScrollViewDelegate), and check yourself if those views are on the visible region or not.

Therefore, it's not necessary to use UIViewController there. Just use views, for example UIImageView. Dynamically create an instance of the view when it's visible, or more desirably, when it's **near** the visible area.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At first I used UIImageView and then turned to uiviewcontroller, hoping to have less memory footprint. As I answered myself, there must be something else I got wrong. Probably the beginning video is not released from memory as soon as it should be.

Comment: I strongly recommend using NSZombieEnabled to find out why your application crashes. If it's about mis-releasing objects, you will probably find it quickly.

Comment: I've already used NSZombieEnabled. The app runs well on simulator. I also used instruments to chec allocations. But the objects alive never exceeded 3MB.

Comment: I see. Any possible issues on the build? Isn't there even some logs or crash reports that seem helpful? I think other people would need more information to figure out what is going on. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I'll just spend a litte more time to dig around.

Comment: I just used Build And Analyze and found possibly 2 or 3 leaks, which never showed up in instruments. Hope this is the problem.

Comment: I learned a hard lesson about ios memory management. I've found the problem though have not solved it. There are some leaks related to [NSDictionary initWithContentsOfFile] in one view controller. And the leak makes a list of subviews get unloaded and loaded again and again.

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue and solved now. Hope it works for someone else. :)
Below is the code example that cause the crash(line 3):

```
UIImage *image = [image imageNamed:@"img.png"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[image release]; // Need not release here!!!
...
[cellView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```